# Can I use Spring Integration without Message Broker

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm building a near real-time data management system and I found out that Spring Integration is exactly what I need to implement the whole data management life cycle in a distributed and scalable way. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve it on different virtual machine without using a message broker (e.g. ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ)

I know that ZeroMQ should probably do the job but (at this time) it seems not to be officially supported by the Spring Integration project.

So, is there a way to distribute the project architecture over many servers using only Spring Integration (without message broker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use built-in TCP/UDP support to start socket servers and clients for them: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html

There is a Zookeeper support as well: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.6.RELEASE/reference/html/zookeeper.html

Also you can take a look to Spring Integration extension for Hazelcast: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-hazelcast.

Also you always can distribute states via many other protocols: shared DB (Mongo, Redis, Gemfire etc..) or even just figure out something based on the shared file system on the FTP.

Yes, there is no ZeroMQ support yet: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3045. But Contribution is always welcome!

Comment: Using the TCP socket, will it be possible to achieve Publish/Subscribe channel strategy?